# Mouseover pause jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to stop animation when the mouseover the text. But I don't know how to stop the animation on mouseover.

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Animation</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function tick2(){
                jQuery('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp(function(){
                   jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery('#ticker_02')).slideDown(); 
                   jQuery("#ticker_02 ul > li:lt(2)").show();
                   jQuery("#ticker_02 ul > li:gt(2)").hide();  
                });
            }
            setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="ticker" id="ticker_02">
             <li>Looong text.....</li>
             <li>Looong text.....</li>
             <li>Looong text.....</li>
             <li>Looong text.....</li>
        </ul> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: -1 for asking `63` questions, and not learning to format your code correctly.

Comment: To include formatted code in your SO question simply indent it four spaces, or type/paste it without indenting then select it and press the `{}` button. You can then include characters like `<` directly rather than trying to use html entities like `&lt;`, plus SO applies coloured syntax-highlighting.

Comment: **you're missing a `<div>`** after `<body>`

Comment: The `jQuery("#ticker_02 ul > li:lt(2)").show();` and `.hide()` calls wouldn't work: the first part of the selector `#ticker_02 ul` won't match any elements...

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

```
$(".someMovingBlock").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 10000); //Start animation.

$(".someMovingBlock").mouseover(function(){ //Stop on mouseover.
  $(this).stop();
});
$(".someMovingBlock").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).animate({left: '-=' + (100 - $(this).position().left) + 'px'}, 10000); //Continue on mouseout.
});
```

Comment: This approach doesn't continue the previous animation, it starts a new animation that will take the element 100px left of where it is at that point rather than 100px left of where it started.

Comment: Yes, but that is just a stop method example. Its fairly easy to calculate element position and how many pixels left to the end of animation and then continue from that point.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/k9SLK/1/) is probably enough... or is there a need to pause the 'real' animation.

```
function tick2(){
    $('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp( function () {
        $(this).appendTo(jQuery('#ticker_02')).slideDown(); 
        $("#ticker_02 ul > li:lt(2)").show();
        $("#ticker_02 ul > li:gt(2)").hide();  
    });
}
var interval_id = setInterval(tick2, 3000);
$(".ticker").mouseover(function(){
   clearInterval(interval_id);                                             
}).mouseout(function(){
     interval_id = setInterval(tick2, 3000);       
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
            var paused = false;
            function tick2(){ 
                if(paused)
                  return false;
                jQuery('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp( function () {jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery('#ticker_02')).slideDown(); 
                jQuery("#ticker_02 ul > li:lt(2)").show();
                jQuery("#ticker_02 ul > li:gt(2)").hide();  
                });
            }
            setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 3000);
                $("element").hover(
  function () {
    paused = true;
  }, 
  function () {
    paused = false;
  }
);
        </script>
```

You can do it this way ,store a global Variable and change it state on Hover-in and Hover-ou event's

Comment: This code not working on mouse over. please help me. very urgent to me.

Comment: @Velmurugan check the Selector ,and tell it when to use Hover Event on which Element ,otherwise it should work like a charm .

Comment: i dont know how to add selector. please help me. i need to stop text on hover.